# Cannot set up resolution for screen on an ASUS A55V

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, external-monitor, bumblebee

I have an ASUS A55V which comes with the infamous nVidia Optimus chipset. I installed *bumblebee*, and tested it correctly with `optirun glxspheres`. The problem is that I cannot change the screen resolution, from both the nVidia Panel and the Ubuntu Display utility, which is fixed at 640x480. The strange thing is that if I attach an external monitor, it's correctly detected and I can configure it normally with a decent resolution.

Laptop screen's resolution is fixed no matter if the external monitor is plugged in or not. And a curious thing is that even if the external monitor is unplugged, it still shows at the nVidia settings...

Any hints on how to solve this?

EDIT: using `xrandr` seems to work to add a new resolution and set it up, but the display is limited to the *center* of the screen. Here's a screenshot so you know what I mean:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the xorg file exists, remove that and reboot. (it would be better if you remove `xrandr`. )

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: That was it, thanks! But it freezes on startup... :(

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you certainly installed NVIDIA oficial driver...
This computer is using optimus nvidia technology then you have to use bumblebee linux packages
http://bumblebee-project.org/

Comment: Nope, it was with bumblebee. I already fixed this, thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setting up a 16:9 resolution from the *Display* panel (1360x768) after adding it with `xrandr` works, but not directly from `xrandr`...